# Android RecyclerView set Adapter works but notifyDatasetchanged() does not in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, observers

I am using the `Observer` class to update my `RecyclerView` whenever a new item is added to the list. Following is my code -

```
Observer<List<StudentEntity>> myObserver = new Observer<List<StudentEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<StudentEntity> studentEntities) {
                //Update Listview adapter
                lstStudents = studentEntities;
                if (recyclerView.getAdapter()==null){
                    MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                }else {
                    //recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); --- This does not work
                    MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"New record added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        };
```

In the if condition when I used `notifydatasetchanged()` the adapter is re-drawing itself but with the old data. However, when I using setAdapter method it works fine. Can you please explain?

Comment: Please Accept and Upvote any of the answers that have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void setupRecyclerView() {
    aDummyList.clear();
    aDummyList = MyListUtil.getaDummyList(); //load data or get data from your source

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(aDummyList);
    myAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            //  checkAdapterIsEmpty();
            if (layoutManager.getItemCount() == 0) {
                Log.w(TAG, " listSize == 0 ");
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "  listSize NOT ZERO ");
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How about this !
And setup your recyclerview config inside onCreate

```
noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(aDummyList, yourContext);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(yourContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(v.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

declare Your before `onCreate()` method like this

```
MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter;
```

than use below condition

```
lstStudents.addAll(studentEntities);
if (recyclerViewAdapter==null){
       MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
}else {
      recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size());
      recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

> **OR TRY THIS**

declare Your before `onCreate()` method like this

```
MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter;
boolean isFtym = true;
```

than use below condition

```
lstStudents.addAll(studentEntities);
if (isFtym){
       MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);
       recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
       isFtym = false;
}else {
      recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size());
      recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: i tried your options. I added recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size()); before calling notifyDataSetChanged(); but it didn't work.

Comment: unfortunately no. The trouble seems to be related to the Observer class. If i call the notifyDatasetchanged() directly from else where then the recyclerview gets refreshed. But same code inside onChanged() does nothing??

Comment: @user1122549 i think you are right because the same code is working fine in my device

Comment: is your code working from inside the onChanged() method?

Comment: @user1122549 for test case add your data in **studentEntities** than try to **notifyDatasetchanged() ** outside the  Observer class

Comment: yes tried that too...but no success. I read somewhere that notifyDatasetChanged() should only be called from the main thread otherwise it will not work. So i add a check to make sure the call is happening on the main thread. But still no luck.

Comment: than it might be issue with your  Observer class  @user1122549

Answer (score 0):

```
MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter;
boolean isAdd= true;


Observer<List<StudentEntity>> myObserver = new Observer<List<StudentEntity>>() {
@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable List<StudentEntity> studentEntities) {
lstStudents = studentEntities;
recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);
if (isAdd){
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
isAdd= false;
}else {
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"New record added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
};
```

Try this first set list in recyclerViewAdapter  and than check for adapter Null or not if null than use setAdapter method otherwise use notifyDataSetChanged method.

Comment: the above code does not work. I am not sure how its different from the code i posted. Additionally, the if condition in your code will throw an exception if getAdapter() returns null.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` as the name suggests, is only to *notify the adapter* that *you have already updated the data set*, so it can go ahead and **redraw**.

In essence, you have to update the data set before your call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

In your case, your adapter should implement an update method, something like `updateStudentList(List<StudentEntity> studentList)`

```
MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter  recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);

Observer<List<StudentEntity>> myObserver = new Observer<List<StudentEntity>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<StudentEntity> studentEntities) {
                        //Update Listview adapter
                        lstStudents = studentEntities;
                        recyclerViewAdapter = new MyStudentEntityRecyclerViewAdapter(lstStudents, mListener);


                        if (recyclerView.getAdapter()!=null){
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                        }else {
                            recyclerViewAdapter.updateStudentList(lstStudents); // You should update the students list before you call notifyDataSetChanged()
                            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"New record added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: the issues seems to be related to the Observer class. I am not sure how. But if i call the notifyDatasetChanged() method from some other part of the code, then it works fine.

Comment: not yet. But can you please explain why i need to create another method in my adapter to updateStudentsList()? Why updating lstStudents data and calling notifyDatasetChanged() is not enough?

Comment: When you create the adapter you are passing `lstStudents` to it. But, when you update the list in your activity, the list inside the adapter does not get updated automatically, you will have to create a mechanism to update the list there.

Comment: If you add your adapter code to the question, I will be able to explain it better.